# In Android which is the best: declaring of Array in code or in resource

Tags: android

Yep I know its easy to fetch n it simplify code n even for localization. But I just wanna know because in android declaration of too much objects is not advisable, And im not too sure if arrays in resource is like dat in code (i.e in terms of object). That is why Im asking which is the best practice in android as we all know that each language as its own do n dont for effective output

Comment: Metrics are relevant on the need. Fast can't be defined the same way in every application.

Comment: Try both and compare. Please post your results here.

Comment: if you define it in resources the fetching is very fast. the delay you see is less then few milliseconds. As a user you won't notice it. it shouldn't matter where you are declaring the array.

Comment: If you declare it in code, how would you handle localization of the application if it was required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the comments point to the answer that there is no real answer. What is the "best" depends on what you're trying to do.

Loading a fix array of strings from resources will be fast and negligably increase the size of the apk. However, as far as I know, a resource is fixed. You cannot add/remove entires to your XML resource file on the fly. You generally see fixed XML resouces when you know the values will not change, like with a `ContextMenu` where you know the options you will be offering will always be the same. In that situation, there is no need to set the values programatically (although you can if you want to).

Declaring the `Array` programatically is more flexible, i.e. it can be modified dynamically, but had other limitations. For example, it is not necessarily universally accessable like your resources file. I'd use the `Array` declared in you Java code if what you're doing is a dynamic function, e.g. generating a user selected list or grouping data on the fly.

As for speed someone who knows more may be able to elaborate but, unless the data size is extremely large, I cannot imagine that there would be huge performance differences for a basic string array in either form.

You just need to balance you're needs vs. the cost/benefit of each possiblity.